# Error de SMTP con PHPMailer, SMTPDebug

Tags: phpmailer, smtp

Trato de enviar correos desde el localhost con PHPMailer, pero no me deja por el `$mail->SMTPdebug`, ya qué ahí mismo me arroja un error y la verdad no sé que pasa. Me arroja ese error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí esta mi código.

```
'<?php 

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

$correo = new PHPMailer(true);

try{

//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;             //Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();     //Send using SMTP
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com'; /Set the SMTP server to send through
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  //Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = 'me@gmail.com';                     //SMTP username
$mail->Password   = 'password';                               //SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = tls;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
$mail->Port       = 587; 
//TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = 
PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('loqueseaprueba4@gmail.com', $nombre);
$mail->addAddress('danielagudelo729@gmail.com');     //Add a recipient

//Content
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = $asunto;
$mail->Body    = $mensaje;
$mail->send();
echo 'Mensaje enviado';
} catch (Exception $e){
   echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}

?>
'
```

Cabe aclarar que utilicé la última versión desde github (26/01/2022), y como tal no debería darme error.

Comment: Escribe el error _como texto, con formato_, ya que no todos pueden visualizar las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Además, pon en el título de la pregunta cuál es el error.

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola Daniel! Creo que el problema de tu código es que te faltó importa la clase SMPT mediante su namespace:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
```

Eso en caso de que estes utilizando composer, si no es así, te recomiendo que verifiques bien la ruta de donde guardaste las clases, puede que sea ese el problema. La documentación lo muestra así:

```
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
```

path: una carpeta donde hayas guardado los archivos de PHPMailer

to: una sub-carpeta en caso de exisitir

Por ejemplo, me descargo PHPMailer y lo guardo en mi proyecto con la siguiente estructura:

[image: Ejemplo de proyecto]

Si estoy trabajando en el index.php mi ruta para hacer el require de las clases de PHPMailer serían:

```
require './PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require './PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require './PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
```

Ya que la carpeta de PHPMailer está al mismo nivel que mi index.php, pero dependiendo de la ubicación del archivo en que quieras usar PHPMailer la ruta debe cambiar.

Espero que te haya podido ayudar, un saludo colega ;)

Comment: Gracias amigo, si me falta escribirle el use al principio del codigo